# Declaração de atributos em uma classe Java

Tags: java

Por que as declarações dessas variáveis foram feitas assim?

```
public class Jogo {

    private Tabuleiro tabuleiro; <<-
    private int rodada=1, vez=1;
    private Jogador jogador1; <<-
    private Jogador jogador2; <<-
    public Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Rita, essa é uma maneira padrão para se criar campos de classe de visibilidade privada, só que sem inicializar. Nesse sentido difere-se do `Scanner entrada`. Consegue ser mais específica na dúvida?

Answer (score 0):

Bom, vamos analisar um fragmento do código:

```
private Tabuleiro tabuleiro
```

- Private: Visibilidade do parâmetro. Define o que pode acessar o
  conteúdo da variável. No caso, **private** define que somente métodos
  dentro da própria classe vão poder acessar e manipular o conteúdo da
  variável
- Tabuleiro: Especifica qual é a Classe/Interface que irá ocupar aquele
  espaço de memória. Quer dizer, define os tipos de objetos que aquele espaço de memória pode ser atribuído.
- tabuleiro: nome da variável, quer dizer, do espaço que memória
  definido.

Existem três pontos importantes a serem notados no código indicado:

1. As Classes **Tabuleiro** e **Jogador** devem ter sido definidas em
   outra classe externa ou interna (Inner Class)
2. Os parâmetros da classe (variáveis globais, que definem as propriedades da classe) foram somente **declarados**, não inicializados.
3. Os parâmetros foram declarados como **Private**, o que é uma boa prática (controle de visibilidade, desacoplamento) na programação orientada a objeto.

2) Uma declaração define os tipos de classe (ou primitivo) que um espaço de memória, alocado a uma variável, pode ser atribuido. Isso quer dizer que você não instânciou (efetivamente "iniciou") a variável, você só atribuiu um nome para aquele espaço de memória e definiu seu tipo genérico.

3) Como os parâmetros foram definidos como **Private**, eles podem somente ser acessados e atribuidos através de métodos públicos (os famosos Setters e Getters) ou através do construtor da classe. O método específico que você pode utilizar depende da sua aplicação, mas normalmente utiliza-se o construtor para inicializar o objeto, e Setters e Getters para atualizar e consultar o objeto. É importante citar que se você instânciar a classe sem fornecer os atributos de tabuleiro, jogador1 e jogador2 e tentar utilizar os métodos **Get** você pode encontrar alguns erros.

```
Public Jogo (Tabuleiro tabuleiro, Jogador jogador1, Jogador jogador2) {
    this.tabuleiro = tabuleiro;
    this.jogador1 = jogador1;
    this.jogador2 = jogador2;
}
```

Assumindo que você possua construtores vazios nas suas outras classes, que também aceitam atribuição através de setters e getters, é possível criar um objeto com parâmetros neutros e depois atribuir valores com os getters e setters

```
Public Jogo () {
    this.tabuleiro = new Tabuleiro();
    this.jogador1 = new Jogador();
    this.jogador2 = new Jogador();
}

public void setJogador1 (Jogador jogador) {
    this.jogador1 = jogador;
}
public Jogador getJogador1 () {
    return jogador1;
}
public void setJogador2 (Jogador jogador) {
    this.jogador2 = jogador;
}
public Jogador getJogador2 () {
    return jogador2;
}
```

Ah... acho interessante citar que não é uma boa prática definir e instanciar Scanner dentro de uma classe, é melhor utilizar uma instância de Scanner definida no seu Main já que, caso contrário, você arrisca criar diversas referências ao Standard Input *(Aquele System.in que você passou como atributo )* simultaneamente no seu código, e pode acabar fechando ele sem querer.